# Plot neural network of nnet object

Tags: r, r-caret

I am having a hard time plotting neural network generated by nnet.  The code I used is:

```
nn <- nnet(y ~ ., data = df, size = 3, decay=5e-4, maxit=200, trace = FALSE)
plot(nn)
```

When I run plot(nn) I get the following error:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
> 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

If I use neuralnet instead of nnet with the following code, plot works fine.

```
nn <- neuralnet(y ~ ., data = df, linear.output = F, hidden = 3)
plot(nn)
```

Don't know why plot does not work if the network object is from nnet.  I also tried devtools library, but there is no plot.nnet function in the library, can't find it anywhere.  I tried plotnet from  NeuralNetTools library, but the plot does not include weights.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi 4Walk, i see that you posted the same question twice. Can you avoid doing this.. Also I see that you don't provide an example data and someone has provided a reasonable answer.

Comment: Also avoid multiple follow up questions, this is unfair to the person who took time to provide a good answer. If there are further questions, please  post a new question

Answer (score 2):

Easiest workaroud (using a dummy dataframe, as you are not sharing your df):

```r
install.packages("NeuralNetTools")
```

```r
library(NeuralNetTools)

df <- mtcars
nn <- nnet(carb ~ ., data = df, size = 3, decay=5e-4, maxit=200, trace = FALSE)
plotnet(nn)
```

which gives you the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, and sorry for not sharing the df, but my df is also a dummy one, just trying to understand.  I was able to d create a plot like you have shared, but I am trying to get the coefficients to show up also, something like this:

Comment: I am trying to copy paste an example plot, unable to do so, I would like the bias and weights to print as well.